# Python json.load() read \u003d as it is

Tags: python, json, unicode-string

I have a Json file temp.json with following content

```
{
  "response": {
    "statusCode": 202,
    "headers": [
      [
        "Content-Type",
        "application/json;charset\u003dutf-8"
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Now when I print the content it prints as it is

```
>>> f = open("temp.json")
>>> print(f.read())
{
  "response": {
    "statusCode": 202,
    "headers": [
      [
        "Content-Type",
        "application/json;charset\u003dutf-8"
      ]
    ]
  }
}
>>> f.close()
```

But when I do json.load() all the "\u003d" codes are changing into their value, we can in the `Content-Type` before `utf-8` it changed to `=`

```
>>> import json
>>> f = open("temp.json")
>>> print(json.load(f))
{'response': {'statusCode': 202, 'headers': [['Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8']]}}
>>> f.close()
```

Is there any flag or any other way to load them as it is?

python version  3.9.0

Comment: What do you mean by "load them as it is"? JSON is a *notation* for data, and in this notation ``\u003d`` means ``=`` just like ``{}`` means  ``dict``. Either you do not parse the JSON, i.e. ``f.read()``, or you do parse the JSON, i.e. ``json.load(f)``.

Comment: What is your desired result for "loading" the JSON ``"\u003d="``? Do you want ``"\u003d="``, ``"=="``, or ``"\u003d\u003d"``?

Comment: What I am trying to do here is, I will load the file, update the value of a particular key using regex and then I will dump the content back into the same file. After doing this all the `\u003d` in the file are changed to `=`. I don't want to change any other content in the file, except the value of given key.

Comment: Is that a *technical* requirement (as in, some receiver of the output chokes otherwise) or a *personal* preference? As far as JSON is concerned, ``=`` and ``\u003d`` are equivalent and exchangeable.

Comment: It is personal personal preference, the java application that uses these files is working without any issue after the change as you said.

Answer (score 1):

That is "what it is"; `\u003d` is one way in JSON to represent the literal character `=`.  If you don't want to parse the JSON as JSON, you have to implement your own (anti-) parser.

Comment: thanks for the answer, is there a way to covert these characters as before while dumping the json to a file?

Comment: What does "cover as before" mean?

Comment: changing `=` to `\u003d`

Comment: Not directly, but the [`json` source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/json/__init__.py) hints at how you could write your own derived class with a custom encoder.